# How to use a Visual Studio sql deployment script in a windows installer

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installshield

We've used a Visual Studio database project to manage our database schema. What we would like to is include .sql output of a database deployment as part of our products installer which is being created in InstallShield.

However when we add the sql script to the InstallShield project and run the installer, the installer fails to run the script. We get an OLEDB error complaining about the :setvar(s), although I could edit the sql script manually and fix it this isn't really a long term solution.

Comment: `:setvar` is not something that OLE DB understands. These are instructions for `sqlcmd`.

Answer (score -2):

Garbage In Garbage Out.  InstallShield just reads the scripts and executes it against an OLEDB connection.  You can tell it On Error Abort, On Error Goto Next Statement or On Error Goto Next Script.  Other then that it is what it is.   If your SQL has problems they need to be fixed.

InstallShield can do search and replace processing on your SQL.  Without a sample of your SQL it's difficult to say exactly what to do but take a look at:

[Using InstallScript Text Substitution to Dynamically Replace Strings in SQL Scripts](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/robo/projects/installshield18helplib/sql-textsub.htm)

Comment: It's funny how I'm getting such a negative reaction to this correct answer.  It's like all the DBA's that I've known over the years that tried to blame the installer when in reality their SQL was fragile.   The reality is InstallShield is using a unmanged OLEDB connection and whatever SQL you generate has to work in that context.

Comment: An old article on the subject: http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/10/rfc-sql-scripts-are-almost-declared.html